# pointers to allocated objects does not have value semantics what does it mean?

Tags: c++

I am reading the Modern C++ Design by Andrei, where it is mentioned that

```
"Pointers to allocated objects does not have a value semantics"
```

For Value semantic example, it is mentioned that  'int' is perfect. 
so

```
int x = 200, y;
y = x;
```

**My Question?**

1) What is the parameter to be considered so that i can claim that is a 'value semantic'.?
 2) Why Pointers to Objects does not claimed to be 'value Semantic'.

**what I understood?**

If you can not copy the variable to another variable which is totally detacted from the original, then that is the 'value semantics'.

Kindly correct me if my understanding is wrong?, and also provide few simple examples.

Comment: The quote, with "does" and "have a" (both wrong), is clearly not real

Comment: You haven't provided enough context to give a good, correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

The quote seems to be out of context.

Plain pointers do have value semantics:

```
char const *x = "x", *y;
y = x;
```

These are C++ references that don't have value semantics. They can be initialized but not re-assigned.

The quote probably refers to function argument passing: an argument to a function can be passed by value (copied) or by reference. By reference in this context means passing by pointer or accepting a reference. In this context an object passed by reference doesn't have value semantics, i.e. no copy of an object is done and all changes to an object made by a function are visible when the function returns. However, all function arguments are copies, in a sense: the arguments the caller supplies get copied into the stack frame (or passed in registers as an optimization) of the called function. Passing by reference fundamentally means passing an address of an object (via pointer or reference). No matter how many times one copies an address it still points to the same object.

Comment: Hi Maxim, Thanks for the reply. Could you Kindly  provide few more additional information pertaining to question?

Comment: @Whoami: Since you took the quote out of context, maybe more context would be helpful. Trying to find a single line quote in a 100+ page book isn't easy. And the context is likely crucially important to answering your question as the word 'value semantics' might have a contextual definition in this case.

Comment: +1 good except that the hypothesis of "out of context" might be amended to "is not a verbatim quote"

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Saying "is not a verbatim quote" would suggest that I have access to the original quote, which I don't. So, "... out of context" was the best hypothesis I could come up with in the heat of the moment.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "value semantics" is widely used, but generally rather loosely defined. I think Scott Meyers had about as good of a definition as any: "do as the ints do."

In other words, an object with value semantics is one that you can treat pretty much like an int, and if you do so, it generally won't do anything surprising. Copying, assignment, applicable operators, etc., all "just work". Each "thing" you create is independent of any others, so (for example) `x + y` won't change `x` as if you'd used `x += y` (which a (completely un-)fair number of string classes have done, for one example).

Answer (score 2):

[Stepanov](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/DeSt98.pdf) gives the following definition of value semantics (which he calls a Regular Type)

```
T a = b; assert(a == b); // 1
T a; a = b; assert(a == b); // 2
T a = c; T b = c; a = d; assert(b == c); // 3
T a = c; T b = c; zap(a); assert(b == c && a != b); // 4
```

I.e., types having value semantics are DefaultConstructible, CopyConstructible, Assignable and EqualityComparible (properties 1 and 2). Furthermore,

> after assigning the same value `c` to both `a` and `b`, we expect
>   to be able to modify `a` without changing the value of `b` (property
>   3).  If `zap` is an operation which always changes the value of its
>   operand, we expect that `b` and `c` do not continue to be equal simply
>   because their values were changed along with `a`’s, but rather because
>   changing `a`’s value did not change theirs (property 4).

Types with reference semantics can obey 1 and 2, but not 3 and 4 (i.e. modifications to one of more objects which point to or reference the same value, affect all of them).

All the built-in types obey value semantics and modifications are localized. This makes them e.g. very suited for pure functions and parallel programming. With reference semantics (e.g. of objects with virtual functions), changes are not localized anymore.

```
T* a = c; T* b = c; a = d; assert(b == d); // 5
T* a = c; T* b = c; zap(a); assert(b != c && a == b); // 6
```

Comment: +1 nice ref to stepanov, whom i suspect is the same stepanov who designed the stl

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yes, it's the same, as you can also see on the site that contains the link.

Answer (score 1):

What you are understanding is correct.  Here is an example:

```
string* str_rptr = new string("hello");
string* str2_rptr = str_rptr;
str2_rptr->replace(0,5,"goodbye");

std::cout << *str_rptr << std::endl;
```

The output of this fragment would print "goodbye" rather than "hello".  After the "perfect int" example you gave, this code:

```
y = 400;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

will print out "200".  The important point is that copying a variable does not prevent changes to one from changing the other.

Comment: So, mainly it is based on the copy operation right ?

Comment: Really any modification.  In the string example, we could modify the pointed-to string by erasing the first character rather than assigning it, and the result would be that both variables pointed to the same string, "ello".

Comment: Note that dereferencing a pointer yields a reference to another object. You are not assigning to a pointer on line 3.

Comment: OK, good point.  Let me edit to have a better modification operation.

Answer (score 1):

SEE [Value-semantics here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/val-vs-ref-semantics.html).

In other words, a pointer (or reference) to an object is not a new unique object, but the pointer refers to the original object you made it point to. So as such, you will have to be careful with pointers, so you make sure you know what you are pointing at and what that will change if you modify something the pointer is pointing at.

Conversely, we couldn't live completely with "value semantics" all the time (in C at least), because you couldn't write a function that modifies the content of a passed in value - which can be handy at times...

Answer (score 1):

Value semantics means, that if you e.g. set `a = b` then a is a copy of b, having the same value but detached from b, so that if you b after that, a still contains b's original value:

```
int a, b = 5;
a = b; //a is 5 now
b = 7; //a is still 5!

//in contrast to pointers:
int* pb = new int(5);
int* pa = pb; //*a is 5 now
*pb = 7; //*a is not 5 any more, it's 7!
```

In that example, a and b are not detached, so no value semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here muddle "pointer" and "object that a pointer points to". Pointers have value semantics: if you copy one pointer to another pointer then modify the first **pointer** the second one is unchanged.

Comment: Yes and no, because there is a duality in pointers. Pointers as mere memory addresses have value semantics. Pointers as references and representatives of the objects they point to have not. That's what Alexandrescu's quote is laying stress on - the objects the pointers point to.

Comment: The objects that the pointers point to **are not** the pointers. The semantics of the objects that the pointers point to have nothing to do with the semantics of pointers themselves, any more than the semantics of an object in an array determine the semantics of an index into the array.

Comment: Of course the objects are not the poitners, and the pointers are not the object. But the pointers are references to the object, they semantically *can* be treated as representatives of that object, and treating them as such means treating them without value semantics. When someone writes "Pete Becker" on some list, its just a bunch of letters, not more. But semantically most people will act as if *you* were on the list yourself, although your name **is not** you. Same for `int i;`. `i` is not an object. It's a name that is a representative for an address, where a bunch of bits in memory lies.

Comment: So any time an object can be used to find another object it's a reference to that other object, and does not have value semantics? That's quite a broad exclusion. Or are pointers magic because that's the way **you** think about them?

Comment: No, I surely don't think about pointers as magic. I think about the proerty "has/hast not value semantics" as context-sensitive, meaning that any *absolute* statement, be it "pointers have value semantics" or the opposite, is wrong, only half the truth or however you'd like me to say it. In a semantic context where you treat poitners as mere addresses, e.g. incrementing them to iterate through an array, they have value semantics. In a semantic context where the pointers only serve as handles/references to the objects they point to, they have not.

Answer (score 0):

The most succinct explanation for your question that I can find is: "Value semantics imply that a modification of copy/clone will not affect original object". Pointers clearly violate this. Not by themselves (as you can easily copy pointers not harming other pointer) per se, but the object they point to.